# How to add data continuity in DataTable?

Tags: c#

I want to continue to add data to datatable that already contains data.

In this method, it was get data like: `dt = { 1, 2 }.`

```
public class GetRowOne()
{
    // some code
    if(contains == null)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        string[] array1 = lstHeader[1].ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            dr[i] = array1[i];
    }
    // some code
}

dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```

Now, in another method, I also create and run same like this code.

```
public class GetRowTwoAndThree()
{
    // some code
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    string[] array1 = lstHeader[1].ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        dr[i] = array1[i];
    // some code
}

dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```

It return new values in `dt` is: dt = { 4, 5 }

I think error at like: `DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();` or line: `dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);`

You will look: when `dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)`. All before data will null, it only add new values to `dt`.

I want `dt` save old data and new data, it should be:

`dt = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }`

Comment: How many columns `dt` have?

Comment: Dear @un-lucky, about 52 columns in `dt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store Data in `ViewState["OldData"]` and after adding new row again store dt in `ViewState["OldData"]`.

If in same page you are calling method then store that in viewstate, you can also store in session or create get set method for that datatable

```
DataTable dt{get; set;}
```

EDIT-:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
            dttest = dt;
        }

        public void GetRowOne()
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Column1"] = "Test";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dttest = dt;
        }

        DataTable dttest { get; set; }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetRowOne();
        }
```

Comment: Then use This DataTable dt{get; set;} After adding set datatable in dt and while adding use that dt and set again.

Comment: Also not working. I tried in the method of a class and other class but it was not working.

Comment: instead of dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray); write dt.Rows.Add(dr); only and try again

Comment: I have done changes in my answer which is working fine at my end